# How to create an .exe from an HTML5 in webBrowser?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, html5-canvas, png, webbrowser-control

I have created an Adobe Animate application that generates an .html file, a .JS file and a .png file. I would like to convert this application to .exe. To do this, I use the "Windows from" application in Visual Studio in which I have inserted "WebBrowser". I indicate then the file and the directory to open the index.html file:

```
this.webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("J:\Mes Documents\bol9\index.html", System.UriKind.Absolute);
```

When I click on "Start" the program tells me "an error has occurred in the script of this page". The error indicates that the problem comes from the "src" lines of the html.

Being a novice in the management of Visual Studio, I would like to ask for your help to solve my problem.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: have you tried to add a different route without spaces? Or with an escape for the space into the path for your src.

Comment: I tried it with a pdf file and it works perfectly. But I don't understand your sentence: "Or with an escape for the space in your src path"

Comment: the path to this pdf file is without blank spaces, right? i will document the "escape" part, asking just to be sure that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the problem as stated in my comment, but you could check about escaping the space in your path:

```
J:\Mes Documents\bol9\index.html
```

you will need to tr a few solutions to your problem, as i can't test myself.

Why spaces can be addressed as a problem? Usually there is a whole history of problems linked to them in programming, as stated in https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Notice that here they talk about URLs, i dont know if the same rules apply to your local path, but you can try.

> URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.
> Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has
> to be converted into a valid ASCII format. ... URLs cannot contain
> spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or
> with %20.

Lastly, if all this doesn't work, you can try to add a backslash to your space:

```
*J:\Mes/ Documents\bol9\index.html*
```

Please let me know if this works, hope i was clear and i can lead you to the right solution.

Comment: Indeed, the presence of a space was a problem and I thank you very much for having corrected me. However, I have another error when I click on "start": "This object does not handle this action" referring to the JavaScript file in the same directory?