# How to generate an HTML5 .exe with webBrowser?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, exe, webbrowser-control

I have created an Adobe Animate application that generates an index.html file, a Berhing.js file, a Berhing.png file and the create.js library. I would like to convert this application to .exe. To do this, I use the "Windows from" application of Visual Studio in which I have inserted "WebBrowser".

In my HTML file are the following lines:

```
<script src="createMoi.js"></script>
<script src="Berhing.js"></script>
```

When I click on "Start" a window opens:

```
an error occurred in the script of this page, code 0.
url: file:///C:/Users/Francis/Desktop/bol05122021/Berhing.js.
```

Being new to Visual Studio, I would like to ask for your help to solve my problem.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: You've asked this [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70215661/how-to-create-an-exe-from-an-html5-in-webbrowser) and accepted an answer. Now you're asking it again, why?

Comment: RedBite's resolution of the first issue generated a new, more specific problem. That's why I'm asking the same question again, but in a different way.